# iOS with NavigationController As Root Make, One Controller ONLY Landscape

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, autorotate, rootviewcontroller, shouldautorotate

I have an app in which the root controller is a UINavigationController.  Push one button, and it pushes another view controller.  Push yet another and it starts an AVCaptureSession with Overlay.  I want THAT view, and that view ONLY to be Landscape, and not portrait.  I have looked at a ton of different tutorials, and nothing is working.

The closest I have gotten is:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

in the viewDidAppear.  However, there are some issues.  One, it immediately goes right back to Portrait.  Two, the other views are still all able to be portrait and landscape and I don't want that.  I need help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my app delegate, I use this code and make sure only portrait mode is selected:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
    {
        SecondViewController *secondController = (SecondViewController *) self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

        if (secondController.isPresented)
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
        }
        else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    else return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can make particular viewController as a landscape by placing bellow method in your appDelegate.

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application    supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if(self.restrictRotation)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

then take one bool property in your appDelegate

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL restrictRotation;
```

and then in view controller where you want to change orientation create appDelegate shared instance and allow restriction to change like bellow method

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}
```

now call this method from your view controller and change orientation as you want.

```
[self restrictRotation:NO];

    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

and the most important thing is to change orientation to portrait when your view will be disappear otherwise all the other viewController also become in a landscape mode.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber     numberWithInt:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    [self restrictRotation:YES];
}
```

I hope this will help you.